# Lisp use member through a list of lists

Tags: lisp, member

in common lisp I have a tree of symbols like:

```
(setf a '((shoe (walks(town)) (has-laces(snow)))
          (tree (grows(bob)) (is-green(house)) (is tall(work)))))
```

all are symbols.

I want to return the sublist that contains the symbol I search for (in this case I might search using the symbol `shoe` and return the entire sublist in which they are contained. the keywords are always in the second layer never deeper

trying to use:

```
(mapcar #'member (shoe my-list))
```

but requires `shoe` to be a list (because of `mapcar`?) things got very convoluted after that. help please!

Comment: `(show my-list)` is trying to call the `shoe` function with the value of `my-list` as its argument.

Comment: Where do you set the variable `my-list`? Should that be `a`?

Comment: Do you also need to be able to find the symbol `has-laces` or `snow`? Or are you just searching for the top-level symbols `shoe` and `tree`?

Comment: see http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_assocc.htm

Comment: Yes sorry my list would be a. The list "a" is divided into 2 lists in this example and they words i am searching for are in the top level of each of those list so I am trying to do a member function but one level down than normal. `(mapcar #'member (shoe my-list))`  i meant to write as `(mapcar #'member (shoe) (my-list))`but perhaps I am completely going about it wrong.

Comment: Thank you Will Ness I will do it all using associative lists

Comment: you're welcome. :) happy trails!

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
(setf a '((shoe (walks(town)) (has-laces(snow)))
          (tree (grows(bob)) (is-green(house)) (is tall(work)))))
```

We can find the first `(shoe ...)` sublist like this:

```
(find 'shoe a :key #'car)

-> (SHOE (WALKS (TOWN)) (HAS-LACES (SNOW)))
```

I.e. search through the list of objects, which are lists, and use their `car` as the search key.

If there can be duplicates and we want a list of all of the sublists which start with `shoe`, then Common Lisp's standard library shows itself a bit clumsy. There isn't a nice function which finds all occurrences of an item; we resort to `remove-if-not` with a `lambda`:

```
(remove-if-not (lambda (x) (eq x 'shoe)) a :key #'car)
```

We can also write a `loop` expression:

```
(loop for (sym . rest) in a and
      for whole in a
      if (eq sym 'shoe) collect whole)
```

We can also make ourselves a quick and dirty `find-all` which can be invoked similarly to `all`:

```
(defun find-all (item sequence &key (key #'identity) (test #'eql))
  (remove-if-not (lambda (elem) (funcall test item elem)) sequence :key key))
```

Then:

```
(find-all 'shoe a :key #'car)

--> ((SHOE (WALKS (TOWN)) (HAS-LACES (SNOW))))

(find-all 'x '((x 1) (y 2) (x 3) (z 4)) :key #'car)

--> ((X 1) (X 3))

(find 'x '((x 1) (y 2) (x 3) (z 4)) :key #'car)

--> ((X 1))
```